# Patterns of inventory instocks

Tags: sql, oracle

I use SQL at work to gather info, but nothing too advanced (yet).

I need to determine patterns of inventory instock and out of stock.

I have a table that shows item, location, inventory and date. I want to see if there is a pattern to the times when an item/location is out of stock and instock over time. The file contains a rolling three weeks of data. If an item is consistently going instock or out of stock in three weeks, then I need to know about it to research further.

An item/location is instock if inventory greater than zero. An item/location is out of stock if inventory is zero or negative.

Thanks for any assistance.

Sample data

```
Item, location, inventory, date
1243, 10,       2,         3/12/2012
1243, 10,       0,         3/13/2012
1243, 10,      -2,         3/14/2012
1243, 10,      -2,         3/15/2012
1243, 10,       4,         3/16/2012
```

Then additional item, location, inventory, date records.

Open to suggestions for output. I just need to see the item/location and how many times it switched between instock and out of stock in the three weeks worth of data.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and desired o/p? Also your table structures too..

Comment: I'm very new, so not sure about table structure or the best way to post sample data.   However, here'san example of data.

Comment: You can type the column names and data from your keyboard and align them properly.That will make the table structure.

Comment: Hopefully it came through above. Using an iphone since work internet security wont let me use this site.

Comment: What does 0 signify? IN or OUT?

Comment: @Vutukuri:Mentioned above its OUT of stock (<=zero)

Comment: Thanks Gaurav.Thats my bad.. missed it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this may be what you're looking for.  This will count the number of times that each combination of `item` and `location` moves from "In Stock" to "Out of Stock" or vice versa.  Note that the first row for each `item` and `location`, cannot be counted as a transition because we don't know the prior status given this logic.

```
SELECT item,
       location,
       SUM( CASE WHEN status = 'In Stock' AND prior_status = 'Out of Stock'
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
             END) moved_to_out_of_stock,
       SUM( CASE WHEN status = 'Out of Stock' AND prior_status = 'In Stock'
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0 
              END) moved_to_in_stock
  FROM (SELECT item, 
               location,
               status,
               lag( status ) over (partition by item, location
                                       order by dt) prior_status
          FROM (SELECT item, 
                       location, 
                       (case when inventory <= 0 
                             then 'Out of Stock'
                             else 'In Stock'
                         end) status,
                       dt
                  FROM your_table))
  GROUP BY item, location
```

This shows that the item went from Out of Stock to In Stock once and from In Stock to Out of Stock once in the sample data you posted.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with your_table as (
  2    select 1243 item, 10 location, 2 inventory, date '2012-03-12' dt from dual union all
  3    select 1243, 10, 0, date '2012-03-13' from dual union all
  4    select 1243, 10, -2, date '2012-03-14' from dual union all
  5    select 1243, 10, -2, date '2012-03-15' from dual union all
  6    select 1243, 10, 4, date '2012-03-16' from dual
  7  )
  8  SELECT item,
  9         location,
 10         SUM( CASE WHEN status = 'In Stock' AND prior_status = 'Out of Stock'
 11                   THEN 1
 12                   ELSE 0
 13               END) moved_to_out_of_stock,
 14         SUM( CASE WHEN status = 'Out of Stock' AND prior_status = 'In Stock'
 15                   THEN 1
 16                   ELSE 0
 17                END) moved_to_in_stock
 18    FROM (SELECT item,
 19                 location,
 20                 status,
 21                 lag( status ) over (partition by item, location
 22                                         order by dt) prior_status
 23            FROM (SELECT item,
 24                         location,
 25                         (case when inventory <= 0
 26                               then 'Out of Stock'
 27                               else 'In Stock'
 28                           end) status,
 29                         dt
 30                    FROM your_table))
 31*   GROUP BY item, location
SQL> /

      ITEM   LOCATION MOVED_TO_OUT_OF_STOCK MOVED_TO_IN_STOCK
---------- ---------- --------------------- -----------------
      1243         10                     1                 1
```

Comment: :Wow looks perfect ,+1 for your approach ,great fan of yours

Comment: This query indicates that I need a CONNECT BY clause.  Can you assist with this required clause?  Thanks

Comment: @user1318132 - I'm not sure what you mean by "the query indicates that I need a `CONNECT BY`".  I don't believe that you do need a `CONNECT BY` clause.  If the query I posted doesn't do what you want, it would be very helpful if you could edit your question to explain exactly what output you want.

Comment: I think your query is going to be exactly what I want, but when I try to execute the query I get an error message that indicates "ORA-01788:  CONNECT BY clause required in this query block.". Then the word "location" on the last line of the query is highlighted.

Comment: User error on my part. Sorry about that. Thank you so much for the query. Its exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Item
      ,location
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN inventory>0 THEN 1 END) AS INSTOCK
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN inventory<=0 THEN 1 END) AS OUTSTOCK
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Item,location;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I won't be able to test until Monday when I get back to work. I can't wait to test. Thanks again.